Django - call Form item by item with AJAX call
I'm new to Django and I'm trying to upload Form's items in my template with AJAX call to avoid refresh.
Thanks to many Questions/answers here I have the following code which is working fine and renders the form as a table.
I would like to do the same thing BUT instead of rendering it as a table, I would like to be able to choose which item to display and use it like this {{ form.item_name }} so I can organise my template like I want.
What should I change ?
view.py
def test_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        my_id = request.GET.get('id')
        my_instance = models_companies.objects.get(id_company=my_id)  
        my_form = forms_companies(instance=my_instance)

        return HttpResponse(my_form.as_table())

    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return redirect('home')

template.html
 function load_company_test() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                data: {
                    id : $('#id_id_company').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../test_view/",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div_company").empty();
                    $("#div_company").html(data);

                },
            });
        }

// I want to populate the div like this 
<div id="div_company">{{ data.item_name }}</div>

